# Using Regexp_Replace with spaces

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an expression like so:

```
Select regexp_replace('Seattle, WA Se', 'Se', 'SE')
```

I want to replace the 'Se' with 'SE' but don't want to touch the word 'Seattle'.  So far, both 'Seattle' and 'Se' get changed to 'SEattle' and 'SE'.

How do I add a condition in the *RegExp_Replace* expression to find and change on the "stand-alone" 'Se'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I add a condition in the RegExp_Replace expression to find and change on the "stand-alone" 'Se'?

Search for a preceding space character (or start-of-the-string) then `Se` then a following space character (or end-of-the-string) and use back references to maintain the preceding and following space characters in the replacement string:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         'Seattle, WA Se',
         '(^|\s)Se(\s|$)',
         '\1SE\2'
       )
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: When I first looked at your answer, I thought, why are you not using word anchors? I did not know that Oracle database does not include this in its reg expression engine.

Comment: @PatrickBacon If it did then it would make life so much easier - especially if trying to match `Se Se Se` - which this answer has issues with (but can be fixed by, first, inserting a repeat of each white space character then, secondly, doing the above replacement and then, finally, removing each repeated white space; however, that's a lot of work which could just easily be solved by the zero-width word-boundary match).

Answer (score 0):

Change your regular expression to

```
'Se$'
```

`$` binds to the end-of-string, so `'Se$'` means that `'Se'` must appear at the end of the string with no characters after it. This will let the trailing `Se` be matched, but the `Se` in `Seattle` won't be.

Best of luck.